# Reliably printing messages in ArcMap Python Console?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-window

When finding a solution to a problem by exploratory programming in a REPL I find it very useful to use print statements to build a log and provide insights into application state and flow.

Unfortunately ArcMap's Python Console seems to go silent after calling some of the geoprocessing tools.

For example:

```
>>> print("test 1")
... arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(source_path, target_sheet, source_sheet)
... print("test 2")
... 
test 1
>>>
```

While if I remove the call to the Excel To Table tool:

```
>>> print("test 1")
... pass
... print("test 2")
... 
test 1
test 2
```

How can I reliably print to the console or otherwise work around this issue?

I am running:

- ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.4959

---

I have read the following QAs on print or messaging in ArcPy but haven't found one that matches the use case of using the Python Console:

- [Getting print statements in Python script to print through a batch file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/getting-print-statements-in-python-script-to-print-through-a-batch-file)
- [Viewing print text while running a script in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142922/viewing-print-text-while-running-a-script-in-arcmap)

Comment: arcpy.AddMessage?

Comment: @MichaelStimson From the console?

Comment: Have you tested this with another geoprocessing tool? I recall having issues with Excel to Table tools in 10.3.1. Is the tool failing?

Comment: @ Fezter Excell To Table is completing without error and producing the correct data.  However Get Count is not producing this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is something odd about the prompt of "..." that you get after your first print statement.

When I type `print("test1")` and use the Enter key I get a prompt of ">>>":

```
>>> print("test1")
test1
>>>
```

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 but I will be surprised if this has changed since 10.3.

---

As a second test I typed these lines of code into IDLE, and then copied them to my paste buffer using Ctrl-V:

```
print("test1")
arcpy.GetCount_management(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\TestFC2")
print("test2")
```

I pasted them into the Python window, followed by the Enter key twice and got the output below.  I think this is the expected behaviour.

```
>>> print("test1")
... arcpy.GetCount_management(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\TestFC2")
... print("test2")
... 
test1
test2
>>>
```

Comment: The three lines have been pasted as a unit.

Comment: What were your precise steps to do that?

Comment: Type in an external text editor (notepad++) then `ctrl-c`, `ctrl-v`.

Comment: Try pasting each line in individually...I've seen similar behaviour when trying to paste a block of code into the Python console.

Comment: OK, print is working after GetCount but still silent after ExcelToTable. It looks like only some tools have this issue.

Comment: ExcelToTable may include Microsoft libraries that Esri has less control over the behaviour of.

Comment: Just to emphasize one part of @PolyGeo's answer:  When multiple lines are pasted, *press enter twice* after pasting.